# Using multiple persistence unit with server provided datasource with Spring and JPA

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa, jboss

I was looking for documentation about how to configure spring LocalContainerEntityManagerFactory where it can use multiple persistence unit from persistence.xml. I want to use jndi datasource. Also if possible I would like to use server managed entity factory instead of localcontainerentitymanagerfactory using

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="entityManagerFactory" jndi-name="persistence-units/pu1"/>
```

Can somebody guide me to the right direction about this configuration? Also I want to inject entitymanager in my dao class using @PersistenceContext

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it's possible to do what you want. Each EntityManager is tied to one (and only one) persistance unit, so if you want to use N persistance units, you'll need to instanciate N EntityManagerFactory's.

The "problem" of doing this, is that then, you'll need to annotate every usage of EntityManager with @PersistenceContext and specify which entity manager you want to use.

Comment: I think I didnt put up the question properly. Yes, I agree with you that we have to define multiple EMF in spring context and annotate the dao with @PersistenceContext(unitName="pu1") and so on. But in spring there are 3 diff ways you can creaye EMF. One is localContainerEMFbean and other is j2ee-jndi where server will provide the persistence unit.

Comment: My problem is when I use the spring with second option where I just want to grab the PU using JNDI and use @PersistenceContext with unitName then spring does not find is and complains about it. Here is the simple code I use to test

Comment: <jee:jndi-lookup id="emf1" jndi-name="persistence-units/pu1"/>

Comment: <jee:jndi-lookup id="emf2" jndi-name="persistence-units/pu2"/>

Comment: I also have two PU declared in my persistence.xml with name pu1 and pu2, both are JTA and use jndi datasource.